# What is the most efficient approach to upload a file when using slower network as 2G?

Tags: android

What is the most efficient way to upload a file (about 1MB) using a SSL connection, while using a slow network speed such as 2G ? How much time should the upload ideally take on 2G if I coded it right ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: better if you use upload with service.

Comment: Yes, I am using a service. I am looking for some help that guides me on making the upload as fast as possible, and also a benchmark on how much time a 1MB file should take to upload using the suggested approach.

Comment: for benchmark you can use an emulator with 2g emulated network speed. http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#netspeed

Comment: Sorry, my question was about testing the efficiency of the suggested approach. What upload time should I keep as a benchmark for 1MB file in 2G in order to know if my approach is efficient ?